# Using callgrind to find out which functions are most intensive

Tags: c, valgrind, callgrind

I have just used callgrind on a file and it gave me a callgrind output. Then I used callgrind_annotate to get the results in a more readable form, and I output it into a text file. How am I supposed to decipher this new file to find out which functions are the most intensive? What is the Ir column on the left? What does Ir stand for?

Answer (score 3):

Ir stands for 'instructions read' IIRC.

I recommend `kcachegrind`, instead, a nice graphical tool that immediately shows everything you need to know.